# Changing VMware Network Configuration

Tags: windows-server-2016, pfsense, vmware-workstation

I am in an apartment that PavlovMedia provides DHCP; however, I'm trying to configure my own private network with a pfSense virtual machine as a gateway.  Mainly, I just want to use DHCP from my Windows Server instead of Pavlov Media's without going out to buy a new router.  Here is the planned [Network Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3osCx.png)

I have Windows Server running DNS and DHCP, with a VMware virtual machine running pfSense. If I have the Windows server connected to the unmanaged switch, the unmanaged switch connected straight into wall jack (Pavlov Media), my machines aren't guaranteed to use Windows as the DHCP server, which is why I don't use [This Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoRMB.png). The issue, in theory, is bridging the pfSense VM to both the outside network (Pavlov) and the LAN network, shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN9IK.png). I don't think creating another network adapter on VMware for pfSense and simply connecting it only the host will work.

Comment: Your pfSense will need two adapters. One "WAN" connected to pavlov, and one "LAN" to your local network (Windows-VM, unmanaged switch, machines). The LAN one will be your default gateway fot this subnet.